Is there any SQL query to extract only number data
I want to ask how to extract only number which is not include word like
ddd99938ddd 38483 eifn321ef

I want to extract just 38483 using a SQL query.
I tried to use REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '[^ 0-9]+', ''), but it needs to be more developed.
If someone knows the correct query which extracts only the number, please let me know.

Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

Assuming there would be at most one pure integer in the string, you could use REGEXP_SUBSTR() with the Java regular expression \\b\\d+\\b:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '\\b\\d+\\b') AS num 
FROM yourTable;

